# Is there a way to make a subset of an Object in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an `Item` object defined as so

```
type Item = {
  amount: number;
  warnLimit: number;
  prettyName: string 
}
```

I'm trying to make a type that has the key-values when the value is of a certain type:

```
{
  amount: number;
  warnLimit: number
} // ItemOnly<number>
```

But instead I'm getting

```
{
  amount: number;
  warnLimit: number;
  prettyName: number
} // ItemOnly<number>
```

For now, I'm using

```
type ItemOnly<T> = {
  [key in keyof Item]?: T;
};
```

And whenever i need to convert an `Item` I do `(item as any) as ItemOnly<number>`, but this still allows me to access the keys with the incorrect type.

I don't know if this is possible, since I'm new to more complex typescript.

Comment: This could also be solved If there is a way to get keyof but limit it based on the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you wrote, I assume you want to pick a subset of properties of `Item` based on a predicate. In this case, the predicate is: *give me the properties for which the value is a `number`.*

In other words, we want to do `Pick<Item, 'amount' | 'warnLimit'>` but without hardcoding the picked property names.

Let's start by creating a helper that targets properties by their value.

```
type PropertyOfValue<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V
    ? K
    : never
}[keyof T];
```

We can now pick the numeric properties of `Item`:

```
type ItemOnlyNumber = Pick<Item, PropertyOfValue<Item, number>>;
```

But we don't have to restrict ourselves to values of type `number`. We can create a generic type `ItemOnly<T>` that selects properties by any value.

```
type ItemOnly<T> = Pick<Item, PropertyOfValue<Item, T>>;
```

```
const item: ItemOnly<number> = {
  amount: 5,
  warnLimit: 10
}
```

Hope that helps!